# proving a set is infinite through bijective correspondence

Tags: real-analysis

As the question says.Consider $X=\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$. Find a bijective correspondence between $X^{\Bbb N}$ to a proper subset of itself.

Comment: My proposal for appropriate tagging: Replace the current one with (set-theory). What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\;X^{\Bbb N}\;$ is the set of all functions from the naturals to $\;X\;$ , we can look at each element here as an infinite "vector" $\;(a,b,c,d,....)\;$ , where $\;a,b,c,d...\in X\;$ . Thus, we can try the following:

$$F: X^{\Bbb N}\to A:=\left\{\,\,f\in X^{\Bbb N}\;/\;f(1):=1\,\right\}\;,\;\;F(a,b,c,d...):=(1,a,b,c,d,...)$$

Check now that

$\;(i)\;\;A\subsetneq X^{\Bbb N}\;,\;\;\;(ii)\;\;F\;\;\text{is a bijection}$

Answer (score 1):

Just shift the sequence one place right and put $0$ at the first coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want another way to keep in mind you can also prove that this set is uncountable.

Take $C$ to be the Cantor set  which is uncountable and every element in it is of the form $x=(x_1,x_2.....x_n....)$ with $x_j \in \{0,1\}$

Take the function $f:C \longrightarrow \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $f(x)=x/2$

which is obviously bijective.

Answer (score 0):

In your setting every bijection between $\mathbb N$ and a proper subset of it, e.g. $m_3:\mathbb N\to\{3,6,9,\ldots\}, n\mapsto 3n\,$ just to name a concrete one, induces a bijective correspondence as requested, because
$\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}=\mathcal P (\mathbb N)$, denoting the power set of $\mathbb N$.

The latter identification is a common one: Elements in $X^\mathbb N$ are considered as functions from $\mathbb N$ to $X$, cf DonAntonio's answer, and the two elements of $X$ are interpreted as 'membership bits'.